# Как сравнить char с string на kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Ничего не происходит, условие `if(letter[indeex].equals(morsec[k])` не выполняется

```
for(i in User) {                                                      
    val morsec = User.toCharArray()                                   
    for (k in morsec.indices) {                                       
        for(indeex in letter.indices) {                               
            if(letter[indeex].equals(morsec[k])) {
             answer = answer + code.get(indeex) + " "
}
```

Код на **Java** который работает нужно тоже самое повторить на **Kotlin**. Может как нибудь поможет):

```
  User = User.toLowerCase();
  User = User.replaceAll("\\s","");
  for(index = 0; index < User.length(); index++) {
    char[] brail = User.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < brail.length;i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < letterRus.length;j++){
        if(letterRus[j].equals(new String(new char[]{brail[i]}))) {
          answer = answer + brailRus[j] + " ";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте оператор `==`:

```
letter[indeex] == morsec[k]
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/equality.html

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#equality-and-inequality-operators

Comment: Проблема не решилась ведь он не сравнивает String и Char, если запустить этот код то он выдаст ошибку "Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Char'". Я делал на Java но не знаю как этот повторить на Kotlin. Код на Java я размещу в главном посте, может это как нибудь поможет)

Comment: @YniTI `letter` - это список строк? так работает `letter[indeex] == morsec[k].toString()`?

Comment: Все робит) спасибо большое, оказалось так просто